# cbind error Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Tags: r

I'm trying to use cbind for different values. it's saying differing number of rows. I have added an example below. each calculated values should be take as column. further rbind used

```
df1<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:5){
  df1<-cbind(df1,i)
}
```

```
out:

1 2 3 4 5
```

output should be something like this creating 5 columns

Comment: The first iteration is trying to cbind an empty dataframe with zero rows.

Comment: I'm trying to automate a process so  empty dataframe should cbind  then 1 to 5  after that rbind process will take place

Comment: Put e.g. `df1<-data.frame(firstcol=NA)` above the loop? You van remove `firstcol` after finishing the interation.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe not the most elegant solution, but it solves the problem in your example.
The problem is that you try to cbind a number (i (length =1) with a empty dataframe (number of rows =0). Therefore R says, that the number of rows doesn't match.

In order to solve this, you must give df1 an inital value (e.g. 0).

```
df1<-data.frame(0)

for(i in 1:5){
  df1 <- df1[[i]] = i
}
```

You can then go on and rename your columns appropriately:

```
colnames(df1) = c(paste0('col',1:ncol(df1)))
```

Comment: ```df1 <- df[[i]] = i``` this  line of code is giving me error can you please check once

Comment: There was a typo. I fixed it ("df1" instead "df").

Comment: ```Error in (df1 <- df1[[i]]) <- i : could not find function "<-<-"``` this is what i'm getting

Comment: Looks like you are having a typo as well "<-<-". You should change this to "<-" or "=".